# Analysing 3 band raster data in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, zonal-statistics

I've got 80+ raster geotiffs with climatic data (mean temperatures, average precipitation...) and I need to obtain zonal statistics for these layers using administrative boundaries. The information of these raster files is codified using 3 band (RGB) colours with interval scales. For example, this one

[image]

Its legend intervals, as per its layer properties, are as follows (*Valores* = *Values*):

```
ESCALA={'Producto': 'precipitacion_acumulada', 'Lista RGBA': [{'Valores': [300, ''], 
'RGBA': ['255', '138', '255', '255']}, {'Valores': [200, 300], 'RGBA': ['162', '23', 
'253', '255']}, {'Valores': [150, 200], 'RGBA': ['0', '106', '213', '255']}, {'Valores': 
[100, 150], 'RGBA': ['41', '145', '248', '255']}, {'Valores': [70, 100], 'RGBA': ['130', 
'191', '253', '255']}, {'Valores': [50, 70], 'RGBA': ['128', '255', '255', '255']}, 
{'Valores': [30, 50], 'RGBA': ['128', '255', '72', '255']}, {'Valores': [20, 30], 
'RGBA': ['201', '253', '130', '255']}, {'Valores': [10, 20], 'RGBA': ['255', '255', 
'164', '255']}, {'Valores': [5, 10], 'RGBA': ['251', '215', '68', '255']}, {'Valores': 
[1, 5], 'RGBA': ['255', '157', '60', '255']}, {'Valores': [0, 1], 'RGBA': ['247', '98', 
'9', '255']}]}
```

It seems to me like XML or JSON language, but I couldn't tell.

So far, I'd performed zonal statistics with only 1 band rasters (DEMs, for example), but I have found [this thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/355430/zonal-histogram-from-3-band-rgb-soil-raster) where the use of `RGB to PCT` tool is proposed for a similar problem. However, it wouldn't use the info included within the file (that XML/JSON code) to set the intervals and, as far as I understand, this should be done by hand. My question is: how could be performed that transformation in an automated way for all my files, so the classes could be retrieved direcly from each file or, at least, with a copy-paste rigging?